# Do any Ranges view-adaptor types (from `std::views`) rely on heap allocation?

Tags: c++, stl, c++20, standard-library, c++26

I know that *at least most* Ranges view types don't require any heap-allocation. For example, you can take a C array on the stack and pipe it through `std::views::take(42)` without causing any heap-allocation.

But I know that there are lots of obscure view adaptors, e.g. `views::join`, `views::istream`, `views::chunk_by`, with more coming every year, and just because *most* view adaptors *today* clearly don't allocate (in *common* situations) doesn't mean that *all* view adaptors will *never* allocate.

By way of analogy: I know that *most* Standard Library algorithms don't require any heap-allocation. For example, you can take a C array on the stack and `std::ranges::partition` it without causing any heap-allocation. But there are a few algorithms (`std::inplace_merge`, `std::stable_sort`, `std::stable_partition`; and their `std::ranges` counterparts) that *do* perform runtime heap-allocation. [We've already got an SO question tracking which algorithms heap-allocate.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46714696/which-algorithms-in-the-standard-algorithm-library-allocate-and-is-there-a-way-t)

Therefore, I'm asking for an up-to-date answer (that might even be maintained/updated in the future): **Do any of the `std::views::` adaptors require heap-allocation,** on any major STL vendor's implementation? If so, which ones and why?

Comment: I believe there isn't. There is `std::generator` which may require heap-allocation, but it's not under `std::views`.

Comment: Don't spam C++ versions in the tags, pick one that you actually use.

Answer (score 1):

No view currently in the standard library or expected to be proposed for C++26 (see P2760) is required to allocate memory on its own.

- `generator` of course may allocate for the coroutine machinery (the exposition-only `unique_ptr<stack<coroutine_handle<>>>` member won't be present in any high-quality implementation)
- many views need to hold user-provided objects that themselves can dynamically allocate memory (e.g., a `single_view<vector<string>>`.

`any_view` - if it were to be proposed - would.